# stack ghci not loading up local modules?

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskell-stack

I have

```
mainLogger.hs
Logger.hs
```

in my local directory where the mainLogger.hs reference the Logger module.

When in `stack ghci` I `:load mainLogger.hs` I get the following error message :

```
mainLogger.hs:6:18:
    Could not find module ‘Logger’
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

However if I can compile `stack exec -- ghc mainLogger.hs` and run `stack runghc mainLogger2.hs` or have `stack exec -- ghci` load the module correctly.

Anyone knows what is preventing `stack ghci` from locating module in the local directory ?

ps : I am not using any cabal file or stack.yaml file in this directory, so it falls back onto my global stack.yaml config

Comment: @Carsten I guess. trying this now. my emacs by default launched stack ghci that's why I am looking into this

Comment: I had to test it to make sure but you should be able to load both if you just do `:load Logger.h mainLogger.hs` - I don't know if you can get GHCi to look for the missing module in the current folder if you have no cabal file (I usually just create one)

Comment: @Carsten yes ! it works. I tried loading one then the other (failed), but giving them both at the same time does work . can you put this as an answer ?

Comment: now unfortunately, emacs does them one at a time, but that's another issue

Comment: yes - based on the description I would have thought that it would look for a correctly named file in the current path (you can see that the path is right with `:show paths`) but nope sadly not

Comment: @Carsten the path look right indeed. I dont know why it would load under ghci but not under stack ghci. the only difference seems that paths are relative in `ghci` and absolute in `stack ghci`.. is it a bug ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to load both if you do it at the same time:

```
:load Logger.hs mainLogger.hs
```

I don't know if you can get GHCi to look for the missing module in the current folder if you have no cabal file but if you create/initialize one this is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

This issue should now be fixed in the latest version of stack.  It seems that when a module imported a local module, stack wasn't including the local directory in its module search path.  In the latest 1.5.1. version of stack, this has been fixed - so you should be able to just type

```
stack ghci mainLogger.hs
```